# Escape special characters in Prometheus metric names?

Tags: escaping, special-characters, metrics, prometheus

When exposing Prometheus metrics from a legacy application, I find that some metrics contain invalid characters such as my.metric, my-metric, my:metric

Instead of changing the metric names in my legacy app (it's massive) I could for instance escape these characters:
my.metric, my-metric, my:metric

Or, I could surround these names in (single or double) quotes:
"my.metric", "my-metric", "my:metric"
'my.metric', 'my-metric', 'my:metric'

Would these play well with existing Prometheus functionality?
Would it be ok to upstream/implement support for any or both of these?

Answer (score 1):

Quotes aren't valid characters for Prometheus metric names either.

The standard way to handle this is to convert the invalid characters to underscores: https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/writing_exporters/#naming

Comment: Understood. My hope is to somehow add support for (at least some) special characters, and my aim with this thread is to find the least intrusive method in legacy Prometheus code.

Comment: Would escape possibilities like suggested above, be possible to implement in Prometheus without conflict with legacy functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus allows only the pre-defined set of chars in metric names, which match the following [regexp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression): `[a-zA-Z0-9:_]`. Other Prometheus-like systems such as [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) allow other chars in metric names. In this case the following options exist for escaping special chars in queries:

- to use the filter on `__name__` pseudo-label according to [time series selectors docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors). For example, `{__name__="metric-name.with special{chars"}` would select time series with `metric-name.with special{chars` names
- to prepend special chars in metric names with backslashes. For example, `metric\-name\.with\ special\{chars`